# Find counter-example about product measure

Tags: measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

This problem is in Real analysis for graduate students, Richard F. Bass.
Problem is the following

Let $(X,\mathcal A)$, $(Y,\mathcal B)$ be two measurable spaces and let  $f \ge 0 $ be measurable with respect to $\thinspace$ $\mathcal A\times \mathcal B$
Let $g(x) = \sup_{y \in Y} f(x,y)$ and suppose $g(x) < \infty$ for each $x$.

I think that $g$ is not necessarily measurable with respect to $\mathcal A$. I have tried to find counter-example but nothing can be applied here.

Comment: Hint: What is the measuer of the diagonal or an arbitrary subset if the diagonal in $X\times X$?

Comment: Could you give me hints in more details?